# C Balanced parenthesis checker

Tags: c, stack

I am having some trouble getting my balance parentheses checker to work. My error is in the following code

```
//while the input is not EOF, take in values.
while (input[i] != '\0') {
  //IF input  is an opener, push onto stack
  if (input[i] == '{' ||
      input[i] == '[' ||
      input[i] == '(' ||
      input[i] == '<') {
    push(&st2, input[i]);
  } else if (input[i] == '}' ||
             input[i] == ']' ||
             input[i] == ')' ||
             input[i] == '>') {
    if (isEmpty(st2)) {
      balance = 0;
      break;
    }
  }
  //if input is a closer 

  if (!((input[i] == '}' && top(st2) == '{') ||
        (input[i] == ']' && top(st2) == '[') ||
        (input[i] == ')' && top(st2) == '(') ||
        (input[i] == '>' && top(st2) == '<'))) {
    balance = 0;
    break;
  }

  i++;
  errorpos = i;
  if (input[i] =='\0') {
    if (!isEmpty(st2)) {
      balance = FALSE;
    }
  }
}
```

My stack implementation and getting user values works fine, but the conditionals do not. For example If I am to enter in `{` as input, the `{` is pushed on top of the stack, however it does not check if the stack is empty at all after the while loop. I have tried moving the `isEmpty` evaluation outside the `while` loop to see if that was the problem, but it behaves the same. Basically, no matter what I enter, the expression is regarded as balanced, so it seems to me that my conditionals are wrong, however I can't figure out what to do from here.

Comment: As with so many beginner problems: Why not start by formatting your code properly?  It isn't guaranteed to immediately solve your problem but it will certainly help you and others to better understand what is going on in your code.

Comment: darn; just re-formatted the code before i've seen 5gon12eder's comment...they're so right

Comment: You'll need to take comments and commented-out code into account, where brackets might not balance. You should also ignore the content of string literals and character value assignments, such as `char c='[';`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a pop() when you encounter an end parenthesis, and you might need to restructure a little to do it. Otherwise, your code looks like it should work to me.

I'm sure there is a cleaner way to do this, but to fix this exact code, I'd add an if check when the input[i] is an end parenthesis and after it has been determined there is no error. The if check would check for an end parenthesis and remove the previous matching beginning parenthesis from the stack.

```
  if (!((input[i]=='}' && top(st2) == '{') ||
        (input[i]==']' && top(st2) == '[') ||
        (input[i]==')' && top(st2) == '(') ||
        (input[i]=='>' && top(st2) == '<'))){
    balance = 0;
    break;
  }
  if (input[i]=='}' || input[i]==']' || input[i]==')' || input[i]=='>') { // New if check
    pop(st2);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems:

- you do not pop the stack when encountering a closer.
- given the above, either your implementation of `push` or that of `isEmpty()` must be erroneous as the stack is never empty if any opener has been seen.

Here is an improved version:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct stack {
    int value;
    struct stack *prev;
} stack;

int isEmpty(stack *st) {
    return st == NULL;
}

stack *push(stack **stp, int value) {
    stack *st = malloc(sizeof(*st));
    if (st != NULL) {
        st->value = value;
        st->prev = *stp;
        *stp = st;
    }
    return st;
}

int pop(stack **stp) {
    int value = -1;
    stack *st = *stp;
    if (st != NULL) {
        value = st->value;
        *stp = st->prev;
        free(st);
    }
    return value;
}

int check_balanced(const char *input, int *errorpos) {
    int balance = 1;
    stack *st2 = NULL;

    for (size_t i = 0; balance && input[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        switch (input[i]) {
          // if input is an opener, push the closer onto stack
          case '{': push(&st2, '}'); break;
          case '[': push(&st2, ']'); break;
          case '(': push(&st2, ')'); break;
          case '<': push(&st2, '>'); break;
          // if input is a closer, check the stack
          case '}':
          case ']':
          case ')':
          case '>': if (isEmpty(st2) || pop(&st2) != input[i]) {
                        *errorpos = i;
                        balance = 0;
                    }
                    break;
        }
    }
    if (!isEmpty(st2)) {
        if (balance) {
            *errorpos = i;
            balance = 0;
        }
        while (!isEmpty(st2)) {
            pop(&st2);
        }
    }
    return balance;
}
```